# INNER JOIN with IN

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

I want to combinate the following function with a table for many numbers(here "400") in an other table in Access with the join function.

```
SELECT tblData.ID,tblData.Data,(
    SELECT TOP 1 d.Data
    FROM tblData d
    WHERE d.Data **< 400**
        AND d.ID <= tblData.ID
    ORDER BY d.ID DESC
    ) AS X
FROM tblData;
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The join function is for arrays.

But you can join two tables, perhaps like this:

```sql
SELECT tblData.ID,tblData.Data,(
    SELECT TOP 1 d.Data
    FROM tblData d
    INNER JOIN OtherTable  
        ON d.Data = OtherTable.Data
    WHERE d.ID <= tblData.ID
    ORDER BY d.ID DESC
    ) AS X
FROM tblData;
```